I made Mux, but I know I can do it with fewer gates, can someone explain?
    Or(a= sel, b= a, out= newa);//newa will be true if sel is true
    And(a= newa, b= b, out= newb);//newb will be b if sel is is true
    //if sel is false and a is true newa will be True
    Not(in= sel, out= notsel);
    And(a= notsel, b= a, out= exept);//in this case should return True
    And(a= exept, b= newb, out= out);

This is my code, you can see my logic from the comments.
My code was acutally slightly larger, but I don't know how to get it smaller than this, I know it can be done in 4 gates (I read it on this site) but I don't know how, can someone explain?
I just shortened it a little so it might not work, before I actually had this:
Not(in= sel, out= notsel);
    And(a= notsel, b= a, out= newa);//newa will be false if nsel is false
    Or(a= newa, b= b, out= newb);//newb will be b if snel is is false
    //if nsel is true but a is false newa will be false
    Not(in= a, out= nota);
    Nand(a= notsel, b= nota, out= exept);//in not this case should return false
    And(a= exept, b= newb, out= out);


You need AND(a,sel), AND(b,NOT sel) and OR both of those.  Right?

You need AND(a,sel), AND(b,NOT sel) and OR both of those.
And(a=sel, b=a, out=maybea);
Not(in=sel, out=notsel);
And(a=notsel, b=b, out=maybeb);
Or(a=maybea, b=maybeb, out=out);


As a general principle, you should always keep in mind that everything in NAND2Tetris HDL happens in parallel. Thus, as in this case, you first generate all the possible outputs, then select the one to output. And if only one of your possible outputs can ever be true (ie: the possible outputs are either all false, or just one is true), as in this case, you can simply or them together.
In more complicated chips, there is often room for optimization where you generate intermediate outputs that are used in more than one place.
